# FluentValidation to find overlaping datetimes within a list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, fluentvalidation

I am wondering if anyone can help me as I am only learning. I am trying to use FluentValidation to validate a list of Date times, to improve my skills but I cannot seem to solve a problem and I can seem to find an example of what I am trying to do. Basically, want I am trying to do is:

1. Check the if the start is not before the end (Okay)
2. Check the if start time and time are not equal (Okay)
3. Check there is no overlapping start and ends on the same day. (Can not do)

I would be grateful if anyone would be able to help me. Code below

```
public class Room
{
    public DateTime RoomBooked { get; set; }

    public List<RoomSchedule> Schedule { get; set; }
}


public class RoomSchedule
{
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
}


public class RoomValidator : AbstractValidator<Room>
{
    public RoomValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(o => o.RoomBooked)
                .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Booking can not be empty");

        RuleForEach(x => x.Schedule)
                .SetValidator(new RoomScheduleValidator());
    }
}


public class RoomScheduleValidator : AbstractValidator<RoomSchedule>
{
    public RoomScheduleValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(o => o.Start)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Start time required.")
            .Equal(m => m.End).WithMessage("Start time can not be the same as the end time.");

        RuleFor(m => m.End)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("End time required.")
            .GreaterThan(m => m.Start)
            .WithMessage("End time can not be before start time.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you could do it.

Firstly, [FV doco](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/custom-validators.html#custom-validators) suggests starting with the `Must` extension to do this sort of thing. For your case you'd do something like this for your `RoomValidator`

```
RuleFor(o => o.Schedule).Must(schedule =>
    {
        if (schedule == null || !schedule.Any())
        {
            return true;
        }

        return schedule.All(item => !schedule.Where(x => !ReferenceEquals(item, x)).Any(x => x.Start < item.End && x.End > item.Start));
    })
    .WithMessage("Schedule can not have overlapping times.");
```

This will give you a single error message if there are any datetime overlaps in the room schedule list.

If you want more control over the error messages; say you want to print out which schedules were overlapping, make use of the `Custom` extension.

```
RuleFor(o => o.Schedule).Custom((schedule, context) =>
{
    if (schedule == null || !schedule.Any())
    {
        return;
    }

    foreach (var item in schedule)
    {
        var scheduleOverlapsAnotherSchedule = schedule.Where(x => !ReferenceEquals(item, x)).Any(x => x.Start < item.End && x.End > item.Start);
        if (scheduleOverlapsAnotherSchedule)
        {
            context.AddFailure($"Schedule {item.Start.ToShortTimeString()}-{item.End.ToShortTimeString()} overlaps another schedule.");
        }
    }
});
```

You could take it further by moving the guts of the check into another method to make the test easier to read, or a reusable property validator if you're doing the same sort of check over and over. I'm not going to cover them here as that's not what was asked for, however they are covered in the above link.

A working example of the above rules can be found [here](https://github.com/rgvlee/StackOverflow/tree/master/Question60404033).

Additionally, I'd consider changing your rooms schedule validator for the start property to `NotEqual` as it looks like you want to fire that validation error when start is equal to end; the `Equal` extension will only fire a validation message if they are not equal. It's like an assertion, if they are equal all is well, otherwise return a validation error. Doco for the `Equal` extension:

```
/// <summary>
/// Defines an 'equals' validator on the current rule builder using a lambda to specify the comparison value.
/// Validation will fail if the value returned by the lambda is not equal to the value of the property.
/// </summary>
```

EDIT: For the overlap check I have assumed start and end times between schedules can be the same e.g., schedule 1 end == 1pm && schedule 2 start == 1pm are not an overlap. Change the comparison to use <= and >= to allow no overlap at all.